# PXE booting times out in tftp

Tags: pxe-boot, tftp, landesk

I'm trying to make some (temporary) use of an old machine. It has no disks of its own, but has a boot-capable network interface (Intel's LANDesk 0.99b).

I got it to obtain the IP-address and other options (including the TFTP-server) via DHCP.

However, when it tries actually download the specified file (`pxeboot12`), *both sides* complain of timeout. The server (FreeBSD-11.x) logs:

```
tftpd[16109]: Filename: 'pxeboot12'
tftpd[16109]: Mode: 'octet'
tftpd[16109]: receive_packet: timeout
```

and the client:

```
PXE-E32: TFTP open timeout.
```

There is no firewall in between the machines -- they plug into the same switch.

With tcpdump I can see the initial TFTP-request -- and the immediate response to it -- but nothing happens afterwards.

Using the `tftp`-client from another machine on the LAN, I was able to download the same boot-file in a fraction of a second.

What could be happening?

*Update*: based on [this article](http://www.netheaven.com/pmtu.html), I disabled the MTU Discovery on the server (`sysctl net.inet.tcp.path_mtu_discovery=0`) and also lowered the server's MTU to 700. Still noworky...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, adding the `-o` option to `tftpd` helped. The option is described in [the man-page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tftpd&sektion=&n=1) thus:

```
-o      Disable support for RFC2347 style TFTP Options.
```

Ha-ha...